# docker build of the hyperledger fabric start kit fails on Mac OS X

Tags: xcode, macos, dockerfile, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I'm trying to install and build the Fabric Starter Kit for the Hyperledger Fabric on the Mac OS X following the instructions on http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/starter/fabric-starter-kit/.

I'm using the Dockerfile that is provided and when I run the next command to build the fabric starter kit it fails:

> docker build -t hyperledger/fabric-starter-kit:latest .

I've made sure that I have the latest version of node and npm.  When trying to build it fails and I first get the following error:

> /bin/sh: 1: npm: not found

I know npm is installed under /usr/local/bin/npm.  I first tried to modify the Dockerfile to add the full path to npm but did not work.  I then tried to run the command from the Dockerfile manually

> npm install hfc

This fails and generates the below error output. Can anyone help?  What am I doing wrong?

> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
>
> node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download: https://storage.googleapis.com/grpc-precompiled-binaries/node/grpc/v1.0.0/node-v51-darwin-x64.tar.gz
>
> node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for grpc@1.0.0 and node@7.1.0 (node-v51 ABI) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
> xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance
>
> xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance

Comment: The last error indicates that you are missing the grpc and node libraries for OS/X. In this case the build will try and rebuild the binaries for your platform. When it does this it needs XCode to be installed. I'm assuming you do not have XCode and therefore the build fails.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I have node installed.  Initially it was version 7 but I dropped back to node v6.9.2.  This did not fix the problem.  I also have Xcode so it's unclear as to what exactly is the problem.  The one thing I was thinking of trying is maybe it can't find the node that is installed under /usr/local/bin.  Perhaps setting up a soft link under /usr/bin for node might fix this?